# How to access member variable from nested class

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to make a Solution class that holds several 1D points and it can be given a center and a number k to calculated the k nearest points to this center.

My code,

```
class Solution {
private:
    int center_;
    struct Point {
        int x;
        bool operator<(const Point &other) const {
            return (x - center_) * (x - center_) < (other.x - center_) * (other.x - center_);
        }
    };
public:
    vector<int> findNearestKPoints(vector<int> &nums, int k, int center) {
        center_ = center;

        // vetor<int> to vector<Point>
        vector<Point> points;
        for (int num : nums) {
            points.push_back({num});
        }

        // partition vector<Point>
        nth_element(points.begin(), points.begin() + k - 1, points.end());

        // vector<Point> to vector<int>
        vector<int> res;
        for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
            const Point &point = points[i];
            res.push_back(point.val);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

but it cannot compile.

The compile error is

```
use of non-static data member 'center_' of 'Solution' from nested type 'Point'
```

So how to fix it? 
Maybe there are other ways to calculate nearest points.

Comment: Get `Point` to hold a reference to a `Solution` or just move `center_` into `Point`. The fact that it's a nested class, doesn't mean it has access to the class nested in.

Comment: @DeiDei - that would be a wildly inefficient solution, you will have 4 or 8 bytes for the reference in every point, which has only a single `int` worth of data. So that's either 50% or 100% overhead. Being points in a vector, there will be presumably many of those. Plus the inconvenience of initializing the reference for each and every point. The reference could be a viable solution but not in this particular case.

Answer (score 4):

Your `Point` class does not have access to the `Solution` class, and so you cannot use `center_` in your Point class code. This is because `Point` and `Solution` are two different classes.

To make your solution work, you will need to provide information about your `Solution` class to your `Point`, or use a different class to do your comparison. I would suggest the former for a quick solution and use lambda functions:

```
bool Point::less( const Solution& sol, const& Point p )
{
    return abs(sol.center_ - x) < abs(sol.center_ - p.x);
}
```

and in your findNearestKPoints:

```
Solution sol{ center };
nth_element(nums.begin(), nums.begin() + k - 1, nums.end(), 
    [sol]( const& Point a, const& Point b )
    {
        return a.less( sol, b );
    } );
```

And on a final, unrelated note why is `using namespace std` so common now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda and capture the `center`:

```
nth_element(points.begin(), points.begin() + k - 1, points.end(), 
            [center]( const& Point a, const& Point b ) {
                return abs(a.x - center) < abs(b.x - center);
            });
```